# How to calculate the initial date based on end dates and months since using R?

Tags: r, datetime, calculation

I have a dataset where there is a column with end dates (these dates are timepoint 2). For example, such dates might be 2023-05-31, 2023-05-30, 2023-05-29. Then I have another column that is months since a prior timepoint (months since timepoint 1). For example, 14.23, 15.28, 30.12.

How do I calculate in R the initial date (aka timepoint 1 date)?

I tried looking at past posts on stack overflow, but most tell you how to calculate time between two dates or only days since. Any help is much appreciated!

I tried using lubridate and interval but cannot quite figure out the right code.

Comment: I believe `lubridate` needs integers to subtract months. Perhaps a close base R estimate is `as.Date(dta$date) - (dta$months_since * 365/12)`? (assuming your data is called `dta`)

Answer (score 0):

Decimal months are somewhat weird, since the might have different length. To get approximate TP1 you could use the average length which is [30.437](https://www.britannica.com/science/time/Lengths-of-years-and-months).

```
transform(dat, tp1=tp2 - mts*30.437)
#          tp2   mts        tp1
# 1 2023-05-31 14.23 2022-03-23
# 2 2023-05-30 15.28 2022-02-18
# 3 2023-05-29 30.12 2020-11-23
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(tp2=c('2023-05-31', '2023-05-30', '2023-05-29'),
                  mts=c(14.23, 15.28, 30.12))
dat$tp2 <- as.Date(dat$tp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jay.sf's solution using the `tidyverse`.

```r
# build dates data frame
dates <-  
  data.frame(
    date = c('2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', 
             '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01', '2022-09-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-12-01')
  )

# calculate average number of days per month in 2022 (different than leap years)
avg_days <-
  dates |> 
  dplyr::mutate(days = lubridate::days_in_month(lubridate::ymd(date))) |> 
  dplyr::summarize(avg = mean(days)) |> 
  dplyr::pull()

# your data
df <-
  data.frame(
    end_date = c('2023-05-31', '2023-05-30', '2023-05-29'),
    months_since = c(14.23, 15.28, 30.12)
  )

# calculate start date
df |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    end_date = lubridate::ymd(end_date),
    start_date = end_date - (months_since*avg_days)
  )
#>     end_date months_since start_date
#> 1 2023-05-31        14.23 2022-03-24
#> 2 2023-05-30        15.28 2022-02-19
#> 3 2023-05-29        30.12 2020-11-23
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>